# Unable to get Knowledge Articles for pageNumber=2 using REST API

Tags: rest-api, knowledge, articles

I am able to get first page Knowledge Articles using REST API.

https://XXXX.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles

The result has articles for page 1

"currentPageUrl": "/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles",

"nextPageUrl": "/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles?pageNumber=2"
....

But when I try to get articles for page 2 using the nextPageUrl above, I get 
{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}

Any idea how to get all the Knowledge articles?

Comment: How many responses are you getting back from your initial call?  What happens if you set page size to 100? (https://...../services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles?pageSize=100) Does the response come back with a null nextPageUrl?

Comment: Hi Shane, I get 20 articles in the initial call. I know there are hundreds of articles. When I set pageSize=100, I get {"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.  That's strange. What if you set the page size to something less than 20?  Just want to make sure we're doing that part right first.

Comment: I get the same error for page size 5
{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}

Comment: Shane, the issue was with URIBuilder I am using. 
builder.setPath("/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles");
builder.addParameter("pageSize", "10");
works.
The following did not work
builder.setPath("/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles?pageSize=10");

I am all set. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Excellent!  I'm glad you got it working.  I'm not sure why that works, but... as long as it does!  Maybe the addParemeter method is putting the parameter in the HTTP request body?? Doesn't seem likely.  Hmm.   **You should post your comment as an answer and select it.  That will make it easier for future SFSE users with the same problem to find.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder I am using.

The following works
builder.setPath("/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles"); builder.addParameter("pageSize", "10");

The following did not work builder.setPath("/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles?pageSize=10");